# share file over bluetooth opp in Android N

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contentprovider, android-bluetooth, android-sharing

What i am trying is to share a file over bluetooth. I have tried below two methods to pass the file name to the `ACTION_SEND` intend. `share` activity is pop'ing up and when i touch the connected bluetooth device, i get a toast saying `Bluetooth share: File Unknown file not sent`. Both the method fails.

```
public void pushFileOverOpp(String filename) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setPackage("com.android.bluetooth");
    intent.setType("audio/mp3");
    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "images");
    File sample = new File(f, "sample.mp3");
    Uri u = Uri.parse(sample.toString());
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, u);
    mContext.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Error , Log-

> OppService:        URI     : /storage/emulated/0/images/sample.mp3
>   OppService:      HINT    : null
>   OppService:      FILENAME: null
>   OppService:      MIMETYPE: audio/mp3

```
File f = new File(mContext.getFilesDir(), "images");
File sample = new File(f, "sample.mp3");
Uri u = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext,
           BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", sample);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, u);
```

Error, Log-

> OppService:        URI     : content://com.example.com.test.provider/tester/images/sample.mp3
>   OppService:      HINT    : null
>   OppService:      FILENAME: null

I have checked the android source code, This error comes when filename is null. Log also says filename is null. But i could not figure out the exact reason. Could someone Please help me out here, what is wrong with my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some study i understood the problem. There were two issues-

> xml tag for external storage(/sdcard/) directory was wrong in xml file.

I changed as below.

```
    <root-path
    name="root"
    path="/" />
```

> URI permission was not granted

```
mContext.grantUriPermission("com.android.bluetooth", u,
            Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

After modifying with above lines of code, File share is working !

full working code-

```
public boolean pushFileOverOpp(String filename) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("*/*"); // supports all mime types
    intent.setPackage("com.android.bluetooth"); //bluetooth package name, default opp

    File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "images");
    File file = new File(folder, filename);
    if (!file.exists()) {
        Logger.e("No such file " + filename + " exists!");
        return false;
    }
    Uri u = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext, mContext.getPackageName() + ".provider", file);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, u);

    mContext.grantUriPermission("com.android.bluetooth", u,
            Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

    Logger.d("Sharing file over bluetooth " + folder.toString());
    mContext.startActivity(intent);
    return true;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this code , it works and share the files using createChooser method.

```
          ArrayList<Uri> arrayList2 = new ArrayList<>();

            String MEDIA_PATH = new String(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
                    "/NewCallLogs/audio.mp3");

            File files = new File(MEDIA_PATH);
            Uri u = Uri.fromFile(files);
            arrayList2.add(u);

            Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
            share.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
            share.setType("audio/mpeg");
            share.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, arrayList2);
            try {
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share..."));
               // getActivity().finish();
                Log.i("Finished sharing.", "");
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "nothing shared.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

For sharing the file only  in bluetooth

```
  ArrayList<Uri> arrayList2 = new ArrayList<>();

            String MEDIA_PATH = new String(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
                    "/NewCallLogs/audio.mp3" );

            File files = new File(MEDIA_PATH);
            Uri u = Uri.fromFile(files);
            arrayList2.add(u);

            Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
            share.setType("audio/mpeg");
            share.setPackage("com.android.bluetooth");
            share.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, arrayList2);
            startActivity(share);
```

Comment: If u have any doubt means notify me.

Comment: Thanks , But this wont work on SDK version 24 or above. That is why I put Android N in the question. Two issues with above code- `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to android.os.Parcelable` - pass parcellable isntead of arraylist. Next `Caused by: android.os.FileUriExposedException:` - we cant use `Uri.fromFile`. :(